# WinApi SetFileAttributes slow-motion call

Tags: c, windows, winapi, icons

Today I did some testing with the SetFileAttributes method and encountered a phenomenon I am not able to explain logically:

I wrote a short C program:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    int main()
    {
        char* strFile = L"C:\\test.txt";

        if (SetFileAttributes(strFile, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)) 
        {
            printf("File attribute changed.\n");
        }

        printf("%d", GetLastError());

    }
```

It is a test program that hides a folder or icon, and I want to do it fast, but unfortunately the process takes 1-2s.
If I hide the icon manually via properties and the checkbox selection 'Hidden', the icon is hidden promptly.

So, what makes the winapi call take so many time? Is there a way to optimize the call?

Thanks.

Comment: Try closing Explorer or have it look at another directory. It might be that the file or directory is considered in use.

Comment: I tried difference directories, old as well as newly created ones, and also tried to set the attributes on a different pc, always the same result. Please have a look at it, too, you will see that it takes its time. And: I want to have the explorer opened or better said the desktop visible (with the icon placed on it) when its visibility changes.

Comment: To be clear, is your issue simply that this is taking on the order of 1 to 2 seconds?  Almost anything with the Windows file system is subject to layers of sludge such as _[for example third party context menu handlers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/file-explorer-is-super-slow-when-i-ask-for/762e8393-e4cd-4157-b8ed-bd86a6a95f80)_, or just plain old low process prioritization.  Also (probably not the cause of what you are seeing) the Windows settings for Explorer (Tools->Folder options->view) can affect how a file appears within the Explorer app.

Comment: Yes, imho it should only take the amount of time it needs to process the manual operation executed via properties and the selection of 'Hidden'. Why should my process/c code have to take nearly 2 seconds? I also tried to set its priority to highest in task manager, but without success.

Comment: is exactly single call to `SetFileAttributes` take this time ? how you measure this ?

Comment: Yep, you can see it with your eyes. I go onto my desktop having multiple icons and folders, then I open the command prompt to start my c code from within. After pressing ENTER it takes nearly 2 seconds, until the folder icon is visible as hidden. I need this effect to be visible in a few ms instead.

Comment: no. i ask how many time take call `SetFileAttributes`. look like you even not measure this

Comment: Explorer probably only checks for or otherwise gets notified of changes to file metadata that need to be reflected in its display every few seconds.

Comment: I think it takes 2 seconds _until the Explorer view is updated_, not until the attribute was set. Try a `GetFileAttributes` after the Set.

Comment: And that code doesn't give an error or at least warning? You're assigning a wide string literal to a `char *` variable. And then not using the wide char version of the Win32 syscall... How is that even working?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Thanks for your suggestions. You were right, the explorer view / the desktop gets only updated after the time I did mention.

I was able to solve the slowmotion issue by using the winapi call SHChangeNotify. It is important to combine the uFlags part with SHCNF_FLUSH, then the change is visible instantly.